# Finding $n$ in a binomial expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

**The question is about finding $n$, given that $$(5+nx)^2 (1+(3/5)x)^n = 25+100x+\cdots$$**

I've tried 2 approaches.

Method 1:

$$5^2 (1+nx)^2$$

$$25(1+(2)(nx))$$

$$25+50nx$$

And on the other hand...

$$(1+ 3/5 x)^n$$

$$1+(3/5 x)(n)$$

Therefore

$$(25+50nx)(1+ 3/5 nx)$$

$$25+ 75/5 nx+50nx+\cdots $$

I haven't include past $x^1$ because in the question it doesn't mention anything further

$$25+15nx+50nx+\cdots$$

$$25+65nx+\cdots $$

Therefore

$$100x = 65nx,\quad \text{so} \quad 100/65 = n$$

However, the answer is $4$ in the answer booklet because of a $10nx+15nx$ to get $25nx$ and divide evenly into $100x$, however, I don't see where I went wrong and need help finding this

Upon reflection, I thought about using the regular binomial theorem formula, as seen in Method 2:

$$(5+nx)^2$$

$$(2nCr1)(5)^2 (nx)^1$$

etc, but I don't think it's the way to go because it doesn't make sense for $r$ to be anything else other than $1$ and that eliminates the possibility of having the constant of $25$

I'm confident in Method 1, but just need some help with finding where I went wrong.

Comment: $(5+nx)^2\neq 5^2(1+nx)^2$